# How to reuse custom module with all in one installation in magento 1.9

Tags: magento

I created a custom module that represents a custom payment method, the steps I follow are;
1) Create a module architecture in /app/local/NameSpace/MyModule
2) Create an xml file in /etc/modules to configure my module
3) Create templates /design/frontend/base/default/template/mymodule

The module works well, but i want to reuse the module in other projects with all in one installation. now, i want to know if i must develop a script to copy the xml file in /etc/modules and templates manually? or there is an existing solution in magento 1.9 to do this operation?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create a Magento Connect package. There's a UI for doing this under the System Magento menu (although the UI is sort of terrible) and some googling around should set you right.  Once you have a connect package, you can install it into any system via the `/downloader` UI (also available via the System menu) or the `./mage` CLI command.

Also -- if you choose "Magento Other" as [the role for all your files](http://alanstorm.com/magento_connect_role_directories), your resulting `tgz` archive can simply get uncompressed/unarchived into any Magento system's root folder.  Also of interest -- [my script for creating Connect Packages from raw tar archives](https://github.com/astorm/MagentoTarToConnect).